# Desktop spaces are moving by their own

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

I am using MacOS Sierra on a MBP 13".
I have set up 4 desktop spaces and noticed lately that two of them are switching once in a while (Desktop 2 going is moved to 3 and vice-versa). Any hints why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System Preferencies` > `Mission Control`

Here check and (if enabled) disable `Automatically rearrange Spaces`